# For what reason makes numpy MGrid some indexing convention by complex numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some problem with understanding. I read the following:

```
class MGridClass(nd_grid):
    """
    `nd_grid` instance which returns a dense multi-dimensional "meshgrid".

    An instance of `numpy.lib.index_tricks.nd_grid` which returns an dense
    (or fleshed out) mesh-grid when indexed, so that each returned argument
    has the same shape.  The dimensions and number of the output arrays are
    equal to the number of indexing dimensions.  If the step length is not a
    complex number, then the stop is not inclusive.

    However, if the step length is a **complex number** (e.g. 5j), then
    the integer part of its magnitude is interpreted as specifying the
    number of points to create between the start and stop values, where
    the stop value **is inclusive**.
```

So if I give real numbers, the content is 'modulo n==0'-wise divided:

```
>>> numpy.mgrid[0:4:1, 10:15:2] 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  1,  1],
        [ 2,  2,  2],
        [ 3,  3,  3]],

       [[10, 12, 14],
        [10, 12, 14],
        [10, 12, 14],
        [10, 12, 14]]])
```

And with complex numbers - the number the integer with j suffix, instead of i for technical purposes - its the length of resulting values in the corresponding axis.

```
>>> numpy.mgrid[0:4:3j, 10:15:5j] 
array([[[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
        [ 2.  ,  2.  ,  2.  ,  2.  ,  2.  ],
        [ 4.  ,  4.  ,  4.  ,  4.  ,  4.  ]],

       [[10.  , 11.25, 12.5 , 13.75, 15.  ],
        [10.  , 11.25, 12.5 , 13.75, 15.  ],
        [10.  , 11.25, 12.5 , 13.75, 15.  ]]])
```

But what's special with complex numbers, that they would be appropriate to reflect this change of perspective instead of a simple flag? Is here another part of real fancyness of numpy?

Comment: It's just a input convention that the code developer chose to use.  Look at the code for this class. This slice is expanded with `np.arange` is the `step` is real, with `np.linspace` if the step is complex.

Comment: ok, then it's like a flag, thanks!